# Office 2007 Standard MSI Active Directory Group Policy install not using MSP admin file

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2007, active-directory, group-policy, windows-installer

We are trying to install Office 2007 Standard on XP machines using Group Policy. The machines already have 2003 installed on them (part of the image).

I created an MSP file by running ***setup /admin***. The MSP contained instructions to upgrade previous versions of office, create desktop shortcuts along with some other UI settings.

I then discovered you can only trigger these settings from a command line install ***setup /adminfile ????.MSP***. I tried putting the MSP file in the **Updates** sub-folder of the installation folder, which I believed would be applied to all installs and maybe the Group Policy MSI install.

I also created a **Config.xml** file, specifying the Key, Company Name etc.

The install runs but the problem is it is not upgrading or un-installing Office 2003 and won't install Outlook 2007 at all. Versions 2003 and 2007 of Word and Excel seem to be installed. I therefore believe it is not applying my MSP file.

I does seem to be picking up the Config.xml because I am not prompted for the Key when I start a program.

I have tried putting the line:

```
<SetupUpdates CheckForSUpdates="Yes"
SUpdateLocation="\\server\Install\Microsoft Office\2007\Standard\Updates"/>
```

in the Config.xml but I can't then add the package to the GPO. It says ***"Add operation failed. Unable to extract deployment information from the package. Run validation from the package to ensure package is correct."***

Without the SetupUpdates element in the xml file, it works fine.

My question is how can I ensure that the settings from my MSP file are applied to the MSI install? If anyone can tell me why Microsoft have done away with MST files that would be of interest too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do not use the MSP file for Enterprise installs, instead you apply the Admin Template via Group Policy.

I installed it using a machine startup script in the end.